# How can a linked list node be defined "recursively"?

Tags: c, linked-list

We've just been introduced to linked list today, I get the concept but the declaration is bothering me, here's the code :

```
struct Node 
{ 
    int data; 
    struct Node *next; 
};
```

Why isn't this an infinite loop of declarations?

How does the compiler recognize a `struct Node` inside `struct Node?`

The way I see it, after turning a blind eye to my second question, is as follows :

1. Create a struct inside which there's an integer and a pointer to a struct 
   of the same type.
2. Create the struct pointed to by the pointer in the first struct, it contains an integer and a pointer to a struct of the same type.
3. Create the struct pointed to by the pointer in the second struct which is a struct pointed to by a pointer in the first struct.
4. ...

Comment: The thing is that you don't have a `Node` structure inside the structure, you have a ***pointer*** to a `Node` structure.

Comment: All pointers, irrespective of their type has same size.

Comment: Which is holding the address of a node structure?

Comment: @AxeonThra Strictly speaking that doesn't have to be true. It just happen to be so on "modern" PC-type systems. However, the size of a pointer is always known and fixed.

Comment: At the time the compiler reads the `struct Node *next`,  it (temporarily) treats it as a pointer to an incomplete type.

Comment: How is incomplete defined?

Comment: It roughly means "it's a pointer to something, and even though I don't yet know the size of the _something_, the size of the _pointer_ is always the same".

Comment: What should be clear is that linked lists are **lightweight dynamically extensible data structures**. This means that they can grow, or contract, dynamically with little CPU and memory charge. In fact to extend structures you simply need to allocate a new memory block and 'link' it by storing the base block address in the node pointer. On the other hand the use of arrays  require extension of large allocations that could require memory relocation, data copy etc (as using `realloc()`) that use more resources. Also deleting elements are simple, unlink it and free memory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 2. Create the struct pointed to by the pointer in the first struct, it contains an integer and a pointer to a struct of the same type.

This is where your reasoning is off. Creating a pointer to something does not automatically create the thing it's supposed to point at. So the fact the first object is created with a pointer in it, does not mean that the pointer will point to something valid. Just like if I write:

```
int *p;
```

It doesn't point to anything. The value of the *pointer* is indeterminate. I can initialize the pointer:

```
int *p = NULL;
```

And it still doesn't point at anything. But I can give it the address of something:

```
int i = 1;
int *p = &i;
```

And *now* is points at something. Same thing with the pointer in the node. The node can only be made to hold the address of some node, but it doesn't have to. This is why a linked list is not just the declaration of a node, but also of a set of functions (operations). It is those functions that are meant to make sure the list is in a valid state. That each node points at another, or at a well-defined terminator.

Comment: I see. But by "The value of the pointer is indeterminate." do you mean that it might point to a random chunk of memory if I don't initialize it to NULL?

Comment: @Luyw - Pretty much. It means (formally) that you know nothing of the value the pointer holds (the value is an address). Using any variable that holds an indeterminate value means the behavior of the program is undefined. This is why one is told that initializing variables (and declaring right before the first use, where a meaningful initial value is possible) is considered good practice.

Comment: @Luyw: yes, exactly. If the value of a pointer is not defined, it will still have a value. If that value is NULL (0), then you're in luck. But if not, then yeah, it effectively points to some "random" chunk of memory.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson - Out of luck. The appearance of working is also a possible manifestation of undefined behavior, the most dangerous kind.

Comment: Then isn't the type in the declaration of a pointer useless? Since I could have a char pointer originally pointing to a memory chunk holding an int value for example?

Comment: I see how I could answer my second question if a pointer's type is ignored while the object itself is uninitialized but it's not the case right?

Comment: @Luyw - No. The type is for static type checking. You'd have to constantly cast to a char*. You may think, okay I'll use void*. But either way you lose the benefit of the compiler verifying that the list contains only structures of the correct type. This does not good software make.

Comment: @StoryTeller: yeah. Being in luck is a matter of luck. And when the luck runs out, you'll be out of luck. That's luck for you.

Comment: @Luyw - The pointer type is not ignored. It is a pointer to a type called `struct Node`. The compiler needs only so much info to know the full object layout (pointers are not the thing they point at, again).

Comment: @Luyw - All struct pointers are the same, that's guaranteed. And coincidentally that's enough to make useful data types. Other pointers may vary. But that goes beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

> Why isn't this an infinite loop of declarations?

Ok first thing first **pointer** is **pointer**, it does not matter does it point to the `int`, `char`, `double` or `struct` it is essentially address of memory where something starts and its size is determined by the architecture. That is why you can declare pointer inside `struct` which you just created. If you run this code:

```
struct node {
    int val;
    struct node next; // NOTE: I omitted * so it is not pointer it is struct
};
```

this will give you an error, because `struct node` is *unknown*, its size is also unknown. So in comparison to:

```
struct node {
    int val;
    struct node *next;
};
```

Pointer type is known, what is unknown here is what it points to. Size of pointer is also known thus you do not get recursion.

To get to the point of **pointers**. In C this:

```
int a = 5;
int *p = &a;
char *c = p;
```

is perfectly legal, and it is up to programmer to keep track of this. So bottom line `struct node *next` is pointer to (address of) presumably next node. This is the reason why you do not have `recursion` occurring.

> How does the compiler recognize a struct Node inside struct Node?

It does not!!! This is why my first example does not work!!!! It recognizes pointer type. You can essentially write it as this:

```
struct node {
    int val;
    void *next;
};
```

and to your machine it will be the same as:

```
struct node {
    int val;
    struct node *next;
};
```

Hope this helps you.